# Reference request: placing a set with respect to the integer grid

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, discrete-geometry, topological-groups, lattices

For $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $Q_x=(x_1,x_1+1)\times ...\times (x_n,x_n+1)$ - the open cube having $x$ in its "bottom left" corner. It seems, I can prove (see a draft [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CDCUqG0aJhmrw35NazFTlzTR0fpccFcL)) the following

**Theorem.** Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. There is $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that 
for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, either $v+K\cap Q_m\ne\varnothing$, or $v+K\cap \overline{Q_m}=\varnothing$. In fact, such $v$'s for a co-meager set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This means that we can shift the integer grid so that there is no cube that intersects $K$ only by the boundary (of the cube).

My proof is not very clever, but rather lengthy, and I am not sure I like the way it is written.

> Is this fact known?

**Edit:** Based on Mathieu Baillif's comment it was possible to give a rather simple proof of a similar fact in the context of general Baire topological group. I am however still looking for a reference.

Comment: What if you consider the set $K=\cup_{n\in Z}\{x_1=0.5 n\}$ (assuming no compactness). The cube $Q_m=(m_1,m_1+1)\times ...\times (m_n,m_n+1)$ and its complement will have non-empty intersection with  any translate of the set $K$, given by $K+v$. Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @DSM in turn, if i understand your comment, you interpreted $\overline{Q}$ as the complement, whereas i meant the closure.

Comment: Thank you, my bad. :)

Comment: Would it work to consider measure instead of density? For any face there is some unit vector $w$ such that if $v$ is a vector such that $v + k$ intersects that face but not the interior, then $v+ k + tw$ intersects the interior for every $0<t < 1$.  But if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are two vectors as above $\{v_1 +tw: 0<t<1\} \cap \{v_2  +tw: 0<t<1\} = \emptyset$. So the measure of all such $v$ must be 0.

Comment: Assume $K$ is convex and compact. There exists a $Q_m$ only if one of the supporting hyperplanes has the form $x_k=z$ for some $k$ and for some integer $z$. Suppose in $k$-dimension, $x_k=l_k$ and $x_k=r_k$ are the nearest integer hyperplanes which sandwich $K$. If neither touch $K$, do nothing. If both touch K, translate it by $0.5e_k$ ($e_k$, standard basis vector). If $x_k=l_k$ touches, while $x_k=r_k$ does not, then translate $K$ by $K+\delta/2 e_k$, where $\delta$ is the difference between $r_k$ and $z$ and $x_k=z$ is the supporting hyperplane sandwiching $K$ between itself & $x_k=l_k$.

Comment: A similar argument can be made if $x_k=r_k$ touches $K$, while $x_k-l_k$ does not. 

The above procedure can be done for each dimension. Finally, by construction, no supporting hyperplane of the form $x_k=z$ will have an integer $z$.

Comment: @cha21 assuming i understood your idea: if a vector "doesn't work", then any small alteration does. I don't think this is true, because the problems can arise in some other region of the set

Comment: @DSM what if in dimension $2$ a cube only intersects $K$ by the corner? then there is no horizontal or vertical support line. On the other hand, even though i think that this argument can be fixed, compact convex is way too narrow

Comment: What I was saying was to decompose it into the union of vectors that don't work for each face/corresponding cube. And it is the countable union of sets of measure zero.

Comment: @cha21 but the problem can occur arbitrarily close

Comment: @erz, you have a point there. Will think about it.

Comment: Let me drop convexity, & keep compactness (and perhaps, connectedness). I'll also ignore the "corner" intersection for now. For a dim $k$, let $T_k$ be the set of tangent planes $x_k=z$. Let $T^Z_k$ be the finite set of closest integer hyperplanes on either side of the tangent planes. For each plane in $T_k^Z$, one can find the distance by which it can be moved on either side till it becomes tangent to $K$. Let this set of distances be called $S$. Choose $\delta_k=\min{s\in S| s>0}$. if $delta_k>0$, translate $K$ by $\delta_k/2 e_k$. Else translate by $0.5e_k$. Do this for every dimension.

Comment: @DSM to be honest, i don't quite understand your idea. Do you deal with every dimension independently? Then fixing the next you break the previous.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that if you fix $m$ then the set $T_m$ of $v$ such that $K+v$ intersects $Q_m$ only in its boundary is nowhere dense ? If you take a point v in the closure of $T_m$ and small ball $B$ around it, then there is some member $w$ of $T_m$ in this ball and hence a point $x$ in $K$ such that $x+w$ lies in the boundary of $Q_m$. Take $u$ in $B$ very near $w$ such that $x+u$ is in $Q_m$, then there is a small neighborhood $U$ of $u$ such that $x+U\subset Q_m$. It shows that $u$ is not a member of the closure of T_m$. Hence $T_m$ is nowhere dense. Applying Baire gives your result.

Comment: (I wrote this comment late at night on my phone, I hope I did not write something silly due to this late your.)

Comment: @MathieuBaillif yes, this works! I was trying to find something along these lines, but my proof is 1.5 pages long and exploits geometrical specifics, whereas yours is just a paragraph and is very generalizable. I took liberty at making an answer based on your comment. Hope you don't mind. Thank you!

Comment: Great. I don't mind at all. Nice generalization !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mathieu Baillif's comment we can actually prove a much more abstract

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a Cech-complete topological group, let $U_n$ be a sequence of non-empty open sets in $G$, and let $K\subset G$. Then there is $g\in G$ such that for every $n$ either $gK\cap U_n\ne \varnothing$ or $gK\cap \overline{U_n}= \varnothing$. Moreover, such $g$'s form a co-meager set.

Of course, in the context of the original question $G$ is the Euclidean space, and $U_n$ is the sequence of the cubes formed by the integer grid.

**Proof.** Observe that $A,B\subset G$ we have that $\{g\in G: gA\cap B\ne\varnothing\}=BA^{-1}$. Indeed, $gA\cap B\ne\varnothing$ iff there are $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $ga=b$ or $g=ba^{-1}$.

Let $H_n=\{g\in G,~ gK\cap U_n= \varnothing,~ gK\cap \overline{U_n}\ne \varnothing\}$. Then, $H_n=\overline{U_n}A^{-1}\backslash U_nA^{-1}$. Since $U_n$ is open, so is $U_nA^{-1}$ as a union of open sets. Hence, $\overline{H_n}\subset\overline{\overline{U_n}A^{-1}}\backslash U_nA^{-1}$.

Since the product is continuous from $G\times G$ into $G$ it follows that $$\overline{U_nA^{-1}}\subset \overline{\overline{U_n}A^{-1}}\subset \overline{\overline{U_n}\cdot\overline{A^{-1}}}=\overline{U_n\cdot A^{-1}},$$ from where $\overline{H_n}\subset\overline{U_nA^{-1}}\backslash U_nA^{-1}=\partial (U_nA^{-1})$. A boundary of an open set is nowhere dense, and so $H_{n}$ is nowhere dense.

The set $G\backslash \bigcup H_n$ is co-meager (and so non-empty). If $g\in G\backslash \bigcup H_n$, then for every $n$ $g\notin H_n$, from where either $gK\cap U_n\ne \varnothing$ or $gK\cap \overline{U_n}= \varnothing$. $\square$